# MongoDB - 2 Sort Levels

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an aggregation query which I'd like to sort with 2 levels.

I have a user collection which has the following fields which are relevant to the sorting:
premium (boolan)
last_online (date)

I'd like to sort them first by premium, then by last_online.

I imagine it as the first sort breaking the result into 2 groups: premium and non-premium.
Then, each group is sorted within itself by last_online.

Therefore the result should be - premium sorted by last_online, followed by non-premium sorted by last_online.

I tried `{ $sort: { premium: -1, last_online: -1 } }`, but it doesn't really give me the result I'm looking for.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I tried on this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5aP--BetROs) to replicate your issue but it seems working fine. Would be great if you can share more on your current unexpected result like how it looks like now :)

Comment: @Ray The result in your example is ids 3, 4, 2, 1. It should be ids 3, 1, 4, 2. (1 is premium, premium should appear before non-premium)
It seems like your example basically sorts by last_online in practice. If you'll notice, omitting "premium: -1" from the sort returns the same result.

Comment: Hi @royi-bernthal, interestingly, I just found out that the mongo playground link give different result/ordering for different execution. Nevertheless, I retry your sorting aggregation in a local MongoDB **with the index {premium : -1, last_online : -1}** added and I seems to get consistent results now. Can you try the same to see if it helps? :)

Comment: Seems to be working, I should've really tested more before creating this question. Thanks Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider adding an index to retrieve a consistent sorting result.

```
db.collection.createIndex({premium : -1, last_online : -1})
```